# How can I replace the seat on my wall-mounted toilet

Tags: toilet, replacement

My toilet seat is broken, so I've had to find a replacement. As it turns out, I need to get inside the bowl to fasten the screws that keep the seat steady. 
I also need to get inside there to get the old seat-holders loose.
Because there is no visible access port, I'm getting worried that I need to remove the whole toilet just so I can attach the stupid seat. There is a small hole on the side of the toilet a little close to where the screw goes but it's pretty small. I can't find a brand name aside from "plus", but the flushing mechanism is marked "tece".

[image: My toilet]

Comment: What's that hole in the side for?

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the toilet.   There is often a brand logo under the toilet seat, between the bolt holes.
That said, it appears to be a Duravit “darling new” wall toilet.  There are two or three models within the range, each gets its own seat/cover.  Measure the length of the top of the bowl from wall to front edge and it will correspond with the spec online at www.duravit.us.   It looks like the elongated version which probably uses toilet seat 0063390000, but you should check.
Good luck!